# Can we use a neural network to perform arithmetic operation between 2 numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

How to develop a neural network which can perform subtraction?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you confused about? Can you share more of the research you have already performed?

Comment: Here is a working example for up to 5 digits, with a train/test score of 99%: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/addition_rnn.py. It uses LSTM layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an easy task. Make some training data, two inputs and one output. this is a regression task. You can train a simple `MLP` or you can employ `RNNs` such as `LSTM` for this task. Take a look at [here](https://gist.github.com/siemanko/b18ce332bde37e156034e5d3f60f8a23).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there has been recent research on this that makes this task more efficient than feeding it in an RNN.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.00508.pdf

There are implementations in multiple libraries.

Comment: While I think it is great you are linking recent work from great researchers, it would be better for the audience if you could summarise that paper in a few sentences. Answers containing only links should otherwise be made as comments.